# How do I make a Docker container for RabbitMQ PHP task consuming

Tags: php, docker, rabbitmq, daemon

I have a LAMP setup in Docker to act as an API for a Cordova project I'm developing.

I've only just looked into PHP enqueuing and RabbitMQ but offloading tasks would be a major help to speed up tasks like photo upload or email sending.

I have this code to listen and consume RabbitMQ messages for sending emails, however I'm not sure how to launch this as a kind of daemon with PHP. I also plan on adding further queue's which would require further listeners so my idea is to have a Docker task container dedicated to listening for and consuming tasks.

```php
use Enqueue\AmqpLib\AmqpConnectionFactory;
use Enqueue\AmqpLib\AmqpContext;

/**
 * Inititate queue
 */
emailQueue();

function emailQueue(){
    // Create consumer
    $context = (new AmqpConnectionFactory(ENQUEUE_OPTIONS))->createContext();
    $queue = $context->createQueue('send_email');
    $context->declareQueue($queue);
    $consumer = $context->createConsumer($queue);

    while(true) {
        // Get message
        $message = $consumer->receive($timeout = 10);

        if($message) {
            // Extract args
            $args = json_decode($message->getBody(), true);
            extract($args);

            // Send email
            $mail = new Mailer();
            $mail->setFrom($from, $from_name);
            $mail->addAddress($email);
            $mail->Subject = $subject;
            $mail->Body = $body;
            $mail->send();

            // Acknowledge
            $consumer->acknowledge($message);
        }
    }
}
```

How can I create a Docker container that will launch my PHP scripts to listen and consume the PHP tasks so as to not block my main app execution?

Comment: too late but maybe help others : you can create Cron job run flock your script

Comment: @aminmahmoudi Cron didn't work in my case as the moment there was a failure it died and the container was shutdown, supervisord gave a more manageable approach with monitoring

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up following the tutorial given here https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/multi-service_container/

Using supervisord I was able to schedule several PHP task consumer scripts with auto-restarts on failure and logging to the Docker logs file for monitoring.